# How to execute a jar file using php? Nothing happens

Tags: php, shell, executable-jar

I have a jar file named `MyJar.jar` and it accepts 4 parameters. I need to execute this jar file using a php script. The php file and the jar file are located in the same directory.
When I try to use the `system` function simply nothing happens, no output no nothing. This is also the case for other functions such as `exec`, `passthru` and etc.

This is how I try to run the file.

```
system('java -jar ./MyJar.jar arg1 arg2 arg3 arg4');
// and also
system('./MyJar.jar arg1 arg2 arg3 arg4');
// and also
exec('./MyJar.jar arg1 arg2 arg3 arg4',$output);
print_r($output);
// nothing works
```

**UPDATE:** Thank for your answers. But I've tried everything. I tried using absolute paths to my jar file. I've tried every possible combination of command relay functions with absolute and relative paths. I tried changing directory using `chdir`. `pwd` shows that I'm in the right path. I don't know what to do anymore.

**UPDATE 2:** I just found out something odd. When I use `system` call and specify a return value, the number `6` is return. If I understand correctly `6` means the proccess has been aborted or something. I wonder what that means?

**UPDATE 3:** After checking the error logs, the following error was generated. Can anyone help me with it?

> dl failure on line 696Error: failed
>   /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-i386/jre/lib/i386/server/libjvm.so,
>   because /opt/lampp/lib/libgcc_s.so.1: version `GCC_4.2.0' not found
>   (required by /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6)

Comment: Is it possible that the problem is with the jar file? Can you run it manually and see if it operates correctly?

Comment: Nope. The jar file is ok. It runs flawlessly from the command line.

Comment: You might need the full path to java specified, I'm not sure if `system()` or `exec()` checks the PATH variable

Answer (score 1):

Check your apache error log, maybe the execution is being blocked and have PHP set to hide errors.

Also, try (just as an experiment) using full paths - both far java and the .jar file.

Answer (score 0):

Do you call your php script from another script with `include` or `require`?

Make a system call to pwd to ensure the correct working path. It should be the same as the path to the jar file

```
system('pwd');
```

Other ways you could fail:
The apache/php user is not allowed to  run the jar file. Try to set a file permission of 0777 (-rwxrwxrwx) or 0666 (-rw-rw-rw) to the jar file and see, if it makes any difference.

Is the file really called MyJar.jar? Is the case correct? Linux is case sensitive. Are there space characters in the file name, then you should quote/escape the filename.

The path to the java executable may not be found.
Try `system('which java')` and then prepend the call to in your system call with the path. Also try an absolute path to the jar file.

---

update
Try to start a Hello World Java Programm from within PHP to test, if it really can be run. So you know the problem is not with the Java Programm itself.

Answer (score 0):

After checking your log, you may find your PHP.ini is blocking commands with something like:

```
disable_functions =exec,passthru,shell_exec,system,proc_open,popen,curl_exec,curl_multi_exec,parse_ini_file,show_source
```

Remove 'system' and 'exec' to allow these functions in PHP.

Comment: The functions are all active. Other shell commands such as `ls` run w/out any problem.

Answer (score 0):

Please look into your domain configuration whether safe mode is on or not for your domain. That will block the exec function